# What is $\int\frac{dx}{\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm looking for the antiderivatives of $1/\sin x$. Is there even a closed form of the antiderivatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2FSin%5Bx%5D%2Cx%5D, were you also looking for how they came up with it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#First_example

Comment: link to explanation of derivation : http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/csc.htm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint:**   Write this as $$\int \frac{\sin (x)}{\sin^2 (x)} dx=\int \frac{\sin (x)}{1-\cos^2(x)} dx.$$  Now let $u=\cos(x)$, and use the fact that $$\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{2(1+u)}+\frac{1}{2(1-u)}.$$

**Added:** I want to give credit to my friend Fernando who taught me this approach.

Comment: GEEZ! WHY DIDN'T ANYONE SHOW ME THIS TRICK WHEN I WAS A FRESHMAN CALCULUS STUDENT?!? Oh,I am so totally stealing this for my students,thanks.......lol

Answer (score 10):

Let $R(u,v)$ be a **rational function** of $u$ and $v$, that is, a ratio of polynomials. Let $f(x)=R(\sin x, \cos x)$. Then there is a **universal method** for calculating $\int f(x)\,dx$, namely the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $t=\tan(x/2)$.

This substitution reduces the problem of integrating $f(x)$ to the problem of integrating a rational function of $t$. This can then be handled by the method of partial fractions.

*Universal* does not mean universally most efficient. We do not suggest the Weierstrass substitution for integrating $\cos x$!

Let's see what happens here. Let $t=\tan(x/2)$. It is standard (see the link above) that $\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}$. It follows that
$$\frac{dx}{\sin x}=\frac{dt}{t}=\ln(|t|)+C.$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\int\csc x\ dx=\int\frac{\csc x(\csc x-\cot x)}{\csc x-\cot x}\ dx=\int\frac{-\csc x\cot x+\csc^2 x}{\csc x-\cot x}\ dx=\ln |\csc x-\cot x|+c$$

Answer (score 4):

As $\sin 2y=\frac{2\tan y}{1+\tan^2y}=\frac{2\tan y}{\sec^2y}$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin x}=\int \frac{(\sec^2\frac x2) dx}{2\tan \frac x2}=\ln\left| \tan \frac x2\right|+C$$ putting $\tan \frac x2=z\implies \frac12 \sec^2\frac x2 dx=dz$ where $C$ is the arbitrary constant for indefinite integral