# How to approach this integral besides Tangent half-angle substitution $\int \frac{dx}{\sin x-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there any faster method to solve this integral besides tangent half-angle substitution

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin x-\cos x}$$

I was trying

$$\int \frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}{\sin x-\cos x}$$
$$\int \frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin x-\cos x}dx + \int \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x-\cos x}dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

I would recommend you to notice that:

\begin{align*}
\sin(x) - \cos(x) & = \sqrt{2}\left(\sin(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)\right)\\\\
& = \sqrt{2}\left(\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(x)\right)\\\\
& = \sqrt{2}\sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: How did you come up with this idea?

Comment: @samsamradas It's [a standard technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729974).

Comment: @Átila It was a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407227

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for sharing. I shall propose a slightly different approach from the given reference.

Comment: If so, shouldn't you rather do it over there? (and vote to close this one as a duplicate and delete your answer here)

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia should I take the natural log of the sin to solve the integral or rather use csc

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the suggestion. I will do it there.

Comment: @samsamradas make the substitution $u = x - \frac{\pi}{4}$ and integrate the $\csc$ function as you mentioned.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia why $ln|sin(u)|$ is not valid?

Comment: @samsamradas because $(\ln|f|)'=f'/f,$ not $1/f.$ But see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331307

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks